# Is there a date / time format that only shows minutes if they are non-zero?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I want a time/date format in a View that renders like this when a time ends in :00
**Sep. 16, 2017 - 2pm**

BUT, renders like this only if minutes are present:
**Sep. 16, 2017 - 2:30pm**

Currently, I use this format: `M. d, Y - g:ia` but I need a way to make those zeros disappear when an event starts at the top of the hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [views conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional), from module page:

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define conditionals (if xxx then yyy)
>   with fields in views. Conditions include:
>   Equal To
>   Not Equal To
>   Greater Than
>   Less Than
>   Empty
>   Not Empty
>   Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the condition.

and here is a tutorial how to use it, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIyZV_Hhccw

Comment: This seems to be an acceptable solution in this instance.  
  
My view is setup like this:  
  
-Date Field 1 (M. d, Y - g:ia) [hidden field]
-Date Field 2 (M. d, Y - ga) [hidden field]
-Views Conditional: If Date Field 1 contains :00, render [Date Field 2] else render [Date Field 1]  
  
My view is complicated by some dates having end times as well, but I think I can build something that works.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a cludge but if your output allows simple html, you can write a format that includes a span around the colon and minutes and use the minutes as a class.  Then hide the span if it's 00.  E.g.

```
M. d, Y - g<\s\p\a\n\ \c\l\a\s\s='\m\i\n-i'>:i<\s\p\a\n\>a
```

Then css of

```
.min-00 { display: none; }
```

I've done this with dates to produce over/under large date/small month displays. If it's coming from a view, you may need to check the allow html option on the field.

Comment: Best hack I've seen in ages, bravo